# How to assign a user to administer one content type only?

Tags: users

I have created a content type "TestContent". I created view using the content type. I can add content using the TestContent and I can see the content just fine in view. And I am the admin. Now, I have created a role "David" and I have created a user "xpress". I also have assigned the user to the role.

Then in Admin > People > Permission: I have selected check box for 'David' for the below items:

```
David: TestContent: Create new content  
David: TestContent: Edit own content  
David: TestContent: Edit any content  
David: TestContent: Delete own content  
David: TestContent: Delete any content
```

I logged out as admin and logged back in as xpress but I did not see the add content, find content for the content type that he has permission. Note that this user only have the permission to add content, edit content, update content, delete content for the content type.

Can you please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpress is not an admin, right? So the xpress won't be able to see the admin toolbar. Have you tried accessing the link of node/add/testcontent, node/node-id/edit? was xpress able to access it? if yes then you need to provide a link/button for the xpress to see when he/she logs in. Then I think you need to use views to show the lists of TestContent where xpress can search/filter.

Comment: 1. node/add/testcontent  - Yes, xpress can see add page.            2. node/node-id          - Yes, xpress can see and edit.           3. I can create a view for him to see the list of contents plus search and filter. Is there way he can add a content and not publish it?  Thanks.

Comment: Then you can create a link for that, either put it on a template, block, menu or wherever then just restrict it to a specific role so that it will only appear if that certain role is logged in. then if you want, you can create a view page or block for the find content, with exposed filter of title and a filter criterion of content type: testcontent restrict it to that specific role also. Did I understand you case correctly?

Comment: You want that specific role to not publish it whenever that role creates new content? you can do that via rules module. It's somehow like this: Event: after saving content, Condition: User has role/s (choose the desired role) Action: Unpublish Content

Comment: Why down voted? was the answer wrong?

Comment: This answer was useful. I was using cell phone and may be pressed it by mistake. Sorry for confusion. Thanks for your help. Also, why down and up vote both gives negative 1?

Comment: As for publishing, xpress may enter 50 % data and then save it for later. He may not have all the information at the time he is adding content. So, I am trying to help him with an option to save it and not publish it. Once he is done completely and he can then publish it. I will follow your all the instruction you have given me. I may come back with some questions. Let me see how much I can do myself. Thank you again for help.